# Frequency parameter and its impact on auto.arima results

Tags: r, time-series, arima, automatic-algorithms

`auto.arima` returns two different models weather I define my time series with `frequency=1` (default value) or `frequency=7` which is the seasonality period for my data (weekly data).

Below the forecasted values when `frequency` parameter is set to 1.

[image: Forecast results with time series frequency set to 1]

And now the forecasted values when `frequency` parameter is set to 7 (which is the seasonality of the data).

[image: Forecast results with time series frequency set to 7]

From the help page (`?ts`) I can see that the `frequency` parameter sets **"the number of observations per unit of time"**.

I don’t quite understand what does "unit of time" refers to. Since my time series consists of daily data, my first guess would be that “the number of observations per unit of time” would be 1 since I collect one observation every day. On the other hand, when I define parameter `frequency=7`, I get better forecasts from `auto.arima`.

My question is:

1. What is the true meanning of the `frequency` parameter? Is it the seasonality period?

Comment: See http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/seasonal-periods/

Comment: Thanks Rob, I'm satisfied with your answer. Frequency is the number of obervations per season!

Answer (score 4):

The `frequency` parameter of the time series `ts()` object the number of observations per season, as mentioned on this article - [robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/seasonal-periods](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/seasonal-periods/).

As my time series is composed by daily observations and because I have weekly seasonality, the `frequency` parameter must be set to `7`. That means, data tends to "repeat itself" every week.